# webservice script on mobile device as service

Tags: android, ajax, facebook

so theres this application that is on facebook, so the source is in an Iframe. The application uses ajax to update and I'm looking to figure out how to send updates manually so I don't have to constantly click on it. every two minutes theres this mission you can do and i'd like to automate it so i can have a service on android that makes sure im logged into facebook, then sends out requests every 2 min and 1 second. can anyone help me with this?

I found the ajax request, new Ajax.Request('/missions/start_mission/1422628013?current_planet=1000002998492&ship_quantities=default', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.Element.serialize($('batch_size_1422628013'))}); but i'm unsure how to actually set it with a relative url like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall the url is resolved relatively to the address of the page the script is executed on. And the first character being slash suggests that the url is to be resolved in relation to the root (i.e. domain name). So I'd go with the name of the server iframe gets loaded from. (like http://awesomespacestrategy.com/missions/start_mission/1422628013?current_planet=1000002998492&ship_quantities=default)

Also, you can use Chrome's developer tools, FireBug or even Fiddler to see exact urls being retrieved when you load page.

But I suspect the server stores your session, so you won't be able to trigger the game action that easy.

**Edit:**
Another way would be to use WebView in an Activity launched by the service every 2 minutes: [Android webview inside a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884568/android-webview-inside-a-service)

Comment: if I html sniff the current session I could. but will try with the domain name

Comment: Sure but you'd have to sniff it every time it expires ) There's also a way to do this using WebView. The service would open an Activity that loads the needed page in a WebView and then execute JavaScript on it that emulates click of the needed button, then closes the activity. It would drive you nuts though, having a stupid webview activity interrupt you every 2 minutes.

Comment: I could have it as a service that wouldnt be in the foreground.

Comment: yeah, but not with WebView - that's a View and can only be used in activities. To execute a script on a page you have to have an activity with WebView attached to it.