# Using WebView.findAll() in an Android Service

Tags: android, service, webview

I have programmed my `Service` like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    loadVariables();
    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.loadUrl(url);
    makeNotification = notificationMaker();
    result = webview.findAll(part1) > 0;
    if (result == true){
        notification();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I want to start it and check if the String part1 was found in `webview` and give out a notification, but it does nothing.

part1 and url are loaded correctly and the notification works too (I checked it by printing them in a toast), so something must be wrong with the `webview`.

Is there a need to display it in a XML file and if yes I think it will not work for a service, right?

Comment: webView.loadUrl is asynchronous.

Comment: But in my main class it works while running the app normal and if I insert == instead of > at line 6 it returns a notification.

Comment: webviews don't load in services AFAIK. they have to be used in Activities only

Comment: if you insert == instead of >, you'll test if findAll finds nothing, which is likely since nothing has been loaded yet.

Comment: How did you manage to use WebView in a service if [WebViews can only ever reside in activities because they are a UI component](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884657/2597758)?  Are you sure this works?