# Android WebView from Service (without Activity)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-context

I try to get a WebView running from a **Service Notification**. The WebView is working fine, but I do not get the alerts and some JavaScript functions running.

This is how I create the WebView (nothing special) :

```
mWebView = new WebView(mServiceContext);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());    


        mWebView.setOnClickListener(new OverlayOnClickListener());
        mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OverlayOnTouchListener());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test/test.html");
```

And this is the test.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");

        console.log("clicked");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button on the WebView, I get the following log message from JSDialogHelper :

```
"Cannot create a dialog, the WebView context is not an Activity"
```

Is there any chance to fix this ?

Comment: This works out of the box for me

Comment: @jampez77 How can this work for you if  [WebViews can only ever reside in activities because they are a UI component](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884657/2597758)?  Are you sure this works?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance to fix this ?

Implement a real `WebChromeClient`, one that [overrides `onJsAlert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onJsAlert%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.JsResult%29). Your `setWebViewClient()`, `setWebChromeClient()`, `setOnClickListener()`, and `setOnTouchListener()` are useless, and I suspect that `setBuiltInZoomControls()` and `requestFocusFromTouch()` are not doing you any good either.

Comment: I will have a try ! Thanks for your fast answer !

Comment: @CommonWare Can you please help me with my question here .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524211/android-fragment-application-context

Comment: Did this fix it? I've overridden WebChromeClient and set a new one which handles onJsAlert() by starting a dialog themed activity, but I still get the error.