# Android Webview application context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I want to preload the web URL before activity launch. So can I instantiate the fragment under application context ?

EDIT :
- creating webview inside Application subclass and retrieving it in the activity .but unable to use it because of different contexts. < This happened if using support fragment library>
- using service component to create webview and retrieving it in activity. same context issue as service is started under application context .  < This happened if using support fragment library>

UPDATE :
I am able create a webview object under application context and retrieving it in fragments as and when needed in any activities. it is working fine on Android OS 4.0 and up . I have tested on Android OS 4 and up. Just in case if any one needs

Comment: Why not load the url asynchronously?

Comment: @donfuxx iam trying to load or url and then let user browse on this webview using web ajax methods on this view. how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instantiated Webview under Application context and called this view inside a fragment after activity launch. it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle an [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) listener do get when your page was completely loaded in an [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and after that add/show your fragment.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Documentation explanation:

> Notify the host application that a page has finished loading. This
>   method is called only for main frame. When onPageFinished() is called,
>   the rendering picture may not be updated yet. To get the notification
>   for the new Picture, use [onNewPicture(WebView, Picture)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html#onNewPicture%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Picture%29).

*See more at: [onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)*

Comment: I want to load the whole page and let user browse on this page . the link doesnt explain it so. please help me

Comment: What you wanna is load a URL in an webview?

Comment: I have a webapp defined on our server . Once I load this webapp main page , User will be interacting directly with the server code using java script. I am thinking of using a fragment so i can preload the main page before showing it to the user. please let me know how to do this ?

Comment: @MarceloFilho I edited my question to be more specific. let me know . i am using webclient already . But Images are not loading properly. is there any link to the public project who is already doing this ?

Comment: will try this. I want to call this webview instantiation before this activity being launched to give a seamless experience without any delay. How to do that ?